# Is there any way to view word documents within Safari on the Mac?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions, ms-office

The title pretty much sums up the question. I have looked, and could not find anything, neither paid, nor free. I know about the [DocPreview](http://code.google.com/p/docpreview/) plugin, however that does not work in Safari 5.1+. There is also the [Word Browser Plugin](http://www.schubert-it.com/free/), it was last updated in 2009, and also appears to no longer work.

Is there another method to view Word documents inline in Safari? That is, if I click on a link, I would like to see the document full window in safari, and not be downloaded, forcing me to find the file and open it separately.

Comment: I don't understand. Can't Safari open a downloaded file directly, without forcing you to go and find it yourself after it's been downloaded? It won't be inline, though.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use Google docs — unless you hate Google :)

1. Install the [NinjaKit](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/os0x/20100612/1276330696) extension so that Safari will be able to use [GreaseMonley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) scripts
2. Install the [Google Docs Viewer script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/109371) from [userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/)
3. Now Safari will show a small icon next to Office documents that redirects to Google for online viewing

Incidentally, [NinjaKit](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/os0x/20100612/1276330696) is a great extension and there are plenty useful scripts on [userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/)

Comment: Nice answer, unfortunately it doesn't look like it will work for me, since the word docs are actually on a password protected web-site, which means that google docs can't access it.

Answer (score 0):

Also found [this](http://hoffmann.cx/safari5-gdocs/)

> This is a hack, at the moment, for the Google Docs Viewer extension
>   that exists on Google Chrome.
>
> I hope to develop it further and clean up the code.
>
> This extension, if you don't know the original one,
>   enables you to preview PDF files and MS Office files using Google Docs
>   Viewer.

It works for Safari 7 too.